# Finding sub set of given set (array) by certain rule (php)

Tags: php, set, subset

I have following problem:

I have list (array) of items, and each of item belongs to category. I have rules that say which of 2 categories can go together. I have method `get_rule_by_item(itemId1,itemId2)` that returns true if categories of given items can be grouped together, and false if they can't.

So I need to write PHP code to group an array of items into best matched groups by mentioned rule.

```
Array
(
    [tQVcIqz] => Array
        (
            [id] => tQVcIqz
            [data] => Array
                (
                    [orderId] => tQVcIqz
                    [createdOn] => 2013-09-30 01:44:46
                    [status] => nije placeno
                    [total] => 2631.00
                )

            [item_data] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item 1 - 1
                            [code] => ITEM1-123
                            [qty] => 1
                            [price] => 12
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item 2 -2 
                            [code] => ITEM2-123
                            [qty] => 2
                            [price] => 123
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item 3 - 3
                            [code] => ITEM3-123
                            [qty] => 3
                            [price] => 12
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item 4 - 4
                            [code] => ITEM4-4
                            [qty] => 4
                            [price] => 123
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [name] => Item 5 - 5
                            [code] => ITEM5-123
                            [qty] => 5
                            [price] => 123
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

this is input array... item data is that array that needs to be split in different subsets... for example here, set of rules is like this :

```
item1 item2 rule
 1      2     1
 1      3     0 
 1      4     1 
 1      5     1
 4      5     0
```

where rule is 1 - if they can go together and 0 if they cant...

And ids of items are starting from 1 , just indexes in array start from 0...

Comment: CV question? Homework? Anyway - provide sample of data and desired result

Comment: 3 hours? Is this for a test? What have you tried?

Comment: If you really start working on it, even if you don't know a word about PHP, it can take around less than 30 minutes to complete (3 hours will be cake). Do some research, Get to work, not ask someone else to

Comment: This is for homework... And ive been working for 10 hours straight with no rest, brain dead... absolutely.. If anyone wants to help, please do it...

Comment: Rest 1 hour, start after it and you ll still have 2 hours left. And can you share the output of those 10 hours so we can assist you with it?

Comment: Stop commenting, just vote it down ... or even better `flag` it.

Comment: Why vote it down without considertion? why not try to help them out?

Comment: This is not the kind of question to do anything, not even commenting.

Comment: Ill post output in 2 minutes

Comment: Can we see your rules code please? Edit them into your question.

Comment: There you go... If you need more info i can provide it... I wrote this php application on my own, but im wasted... really wasted...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function group_ok($code, $group) {
    if (!is_array($group)) return TRUE;
    foreach($group as $item){
        if ($this->get_rules_items($code, $item) === FALSE) return FALSE;}
    return TRUE;
}

function remove($arr,$val){
    if(($key = array_search($val, $arr)) !== false) {
        unset($arr[$key]);
    }
    return $arr;
}


function get_user_orders(){
    $userId = $this->tank_auth->get_user_id();

    $res = $this->shop->get_orders_by_user($userId);

    foreach($res as $key => $val){
        $it = array();
        foreach($val['item_data'] as $items) $it[] = $items['id'];
    }

    $k=0;
    $group = array();

    while(sizeof($it)>0){
        foreach($it as $item){

            if($this->group_ok($item,$group[$k])){
                $group[$k][] = $item;
                $it = $this->remove($it,$item);

            }
        }

        $k++;
    }
```

Assuming that $res gets the array like i posted in quetion -> this is the solution. Wrote it down 2 hours after my question, just needed to think trough... Thanks for all.. And sorry if question was inappropriate... And for the voting down, elitist jerks did it...